# How to find function address in a running process?

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I have a compiled C code that makes a call to `LoadLibrary`

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("hello.dll");
    if (hMod == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load hello.dll library\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am running the compiled binary using another compiled C code that uses `CreateProcess` like so

```
CreateProcess(fname, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL,NULL, &si, pi)
```

`pi` is passed by reference to the function running this line.

`fname` refers to the binary path of the above compiled code.

Now using another function that takes `PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi` as a parameter, I want to check for the `LoadLibrary` address in that process.

Can someone explain how to find the address of the function in that process?

Comment: ASLR is seeded at boot time. If you want to know the address of a symbol exported by a module in a foreign process, you can ask for the address of that symbol in *your* process (so long as either process has the module loaded and they target the same architecture).

Comment: @IInspectable can you elaborate more I don't seem to get you response.

Comment: The address of `LoadLibraryW` in your process is the same as the address of `LoadLibraryW` in *victim.exe*. The easiest way to find the address of `LoadLibraryW` in *victim.exe* is by looking at the address of `LoadLibraryW` in your process.

Comment: Note that when creating a process using the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` creation flag, no modules are mapped into the process' address space (except *ntdll.dll*). The calling process can still predict where `LoadLibraryW` will eventually live in that process by looking at where it lives in the calling process. Unless you somehow arrange for the future load address to be taken before the process gets to load the *kernel32.dll* module.

Comment: Or you may [enumerate All Modules For a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process) before the process terminates.